# Vim navigation clunkiness

Tags: vim

I've committed myself to diving into vim to become faster at writing code for ruby/python and I'm having a hard time navigating around files.

Mainly, I'm referring to switching between insert mode and navigation modes. Maybe I'm just not completely used to the editor yet but it feels very awkward to constantly be switching in and out of insert mode.

Is this something that will go away with time? Are there any tricks to getting quicker at moving in and out of insert mode?

Comment: As you use it you will become more comfortable. You'll also find that there are many ways to do the same thing (more or less) and you'll find a way that works for you. I find with Vim you are always learning new ways to do things.

Comment: I apologize if this sounds confrontational, but WHY would you want to be using `vim` (as opposed to some other advanced programming-friendly editor/IDE) if the modal editing is pretty much the main distinguishing characteristic of vim? (Any other feature can likely be found in other editors). For full disclosure, I can use vi when I need to but would never consider vim as my main editor precisely because I can't get used to modes even after 10+ years of being familiar with vi.

Comment: @DVK modal thinking works for some people and not others.  I don't think there's anything wrong with that.  For some people (like me) modal editing feels natural and being in "normal" mode lets you navigate/delete/yank/change a variety of things with very few keystrokes and minimal chording.

Comment: @ted - the problem is NOT with modal thinking required by vim. As you said, some people are into it. The issue is, why would someone choose vim over another editor unless modal thinking is ALREADY on their lists of big pluses (or non-minuses) as far as features? I'm not saying vim does not have any useful features, I'm merely asking which ones does it have that non-modal-editors lack. If the answer is none, Sean is better off trying non-vi editor for comparison.

Comment: @DVK I see what you were getting at now.  Modal editing really is vim's biggest differentiator.  Other features that it has (nice scriptability, good/vibrant helpful community, ubiquity, quick startup time) aren't things unique to vim.  If modal thinking doesn't click for the OP, I agree with you that after a solid effort that another editor/IDE could be a better choice.

Comment: The thing that really motivated me to dive into vim 100% and learn it inside and out was noticing that using other editors (mainly gEdit in this instance), I found myself really hurting at the lack of extensibility as far as customizing the editor went. I don't think I'm proposing that modal editing bothers me, I think it is an excellent feature and enjoy using it. My question was mainly aimed at asking how can I move between the modes faster. I apologize if that didn't come across in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people like to define `jj` or `jk` as something to type while in insert mode to go back to normal mode (rather than hitting escape), this keeps your hands on the home row and speeds things up.  You can put this in your .vimrc to do this mappings (or just choose one of them):

```
inoremap jj <ESC>
inoremap jk <ESC>
```

If you really need to type either of these strings (super rare for me), you can just type the first letter and pause for a couple of seconds, then type the 2nd one.

I also find that really understanding all of the movement keys while in normal mode helps to understand the power of movement within vim and how it gets you to the place you want to go more quickly (thus offsetting and beating the overhead of having to go into/leave insert mode).

To this end, I threw together [a vim movement wallpaper](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/10/04/vim-movement-shortcuts-wallpaper/) dedicated to visually showing the various movement commands relative to the current cursor position (the center of the screen).  Having this up, helped me commit them to memory and made me *much* quicker.

Additionally, understanding the various basic insert keys, helps you get into insert mode in the right place:

- `i` - insert before the letter the cursor is on
- `a` - append after the letter the cursor is on
- `I` - insert at the beginning of the current line
- `A` - append at the end of the current line
- `o` - open up a new line below the current line
- `O` - open up a new line above the current line

Also learning/understanding the various delete, change, substitution and find/replace regexp commands should probably come next.

Comment: I use the jj key binding to move out of insert mode. It becomes second nature... sometimes too much so (I'm constantly typing jj in Visual Studio after a Vim session).

Comment: I use `jk` and I can strongly recommend it. `jj` is also a great choice, but personally I prefer the former.

Comment: I may consider using jk actually. It's easy and (slightly) faster. It it still has the advantage that you rarely find words (in English) with those letters in succession.

Answer (score 7):

Read the "Misconception #1" part of this excellent article: http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html

Comment: Always hitting `<esc>` when I am done inserting is something my fingers have known for a long time but I've never really thought about. Insightful